# QT: Memory Issue. Can't access a Class

Tags: qt

If Qt Works like regular C++, how come i can't access my class object using methods? For example, I declared a pointer to a foo object in the private field of the class MainWindow.h
I have a method called setFoo() as a function for class MainWindow that instantiate the foo object. The setFoo() function is called from an event when a button is pressed, which I called on_button_1_clicked. I can access my foo class within this function. However when I call on_button_2_clicked, the foo class is inaccessible.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_1_clicked() {
    this->setFoo();
    qDebug() << QString::fromStdString(this->confirmName());
}
```

The code above will print out one of my class data elements.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_click() {
    qDebug() << QString::fromStdString(this->confirmName());
}
```

The code above will print out nothing.

I'm new to QT5 and any help will be great since i've been banging my head over this for a while, and maybe its the wrong way to approach QT in general.

Full Code:
    #include

```
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void setPlayer(int);
    std::string getName();
    std::string confirmName();

~MainWindow();

private slots:
   void on_pushButton_clicked();

   void on_pushButton_2_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Board * board;
```

The code above is a standard MainWindow but with class board included

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "Board.h"
#include <string>
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
this->setPlayer(2);
qDebug() << QString::fromStdString(this->confirmName());
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    qDebug() << QString::fromStdString(this->confirmName());
}

void MainWindow::setPlayer( int num ) {
    board= new Board( num );
    std::string name_string[2] = {"INPUT1","INPUT2"};
    board->addNames( name_string );
    qDebug() << QString::fromStdString( getName() ) << endl;
}

std::string MainWindow::confirmName() {
    qDebug() << "Confirming Name" << endl;
    this->board->test();
    Player ** tmp_player = this->board->getPlayer();
    std::string tmp_string = tmp_player[0]->getName();
    return tmp_string;
}
```

Output:

```
/*clicked button1*/
“INPUT1”
Confirming Name
“INPUT1” 
/*clicked button2*/
Confirming Name
“”
```

Comment: You need to show us more of your code. Also, it's not clear how `setFoo()` relates to `confirmName()`, or how the failure of `on_pushButton_2_click()` to print anything out implies that "the foo class is inaccessible".

Comment: Also, the comment "If Qt works like regular C++" makes it sound like Qt is some variant of C++. Qt is not an alternative C++ compiler. Qt is a library. A huge library, perhaps, but still just a library (or technically speaking a *collection* of libraries). Perhaps you just meant that the Qt container classes are alternatives to STL?

Comment: yeah more details will help in answering question

Comment: I added more code, I hope it helps

Comment: Well its inaccessible because in method on_pushButton_1_clicked, it printed properly, but in method on_pushButton_2_clicked, it didn't print anything. Therefore, there must be some sort of memory issue or my lack of understanding. I recreated the same thing without the gui in regular c++, and it worked. I can't figure why it won't using QT and c++ together.

Comment: How do you know that `on_pushButton_2_clicked()` is called at all?

Comment: I include the output above

Comment: What is the code of `confirmName()`?

Comment: If you scroll down to bottom of MainWindow.cpp, it is there.

Comment: Please cleanup your question and your code... both are confusing. Also try to reduce your example code to the essential part that is necessary to demonstrate the problem. And most important: Tell us your problem: What do you expect? What does it do instead?

Answer (score 0):

Saying Qt works differently to other C++ programs is like saying the Earth behaves differently to other planets because the other planets don't have humans.

As far as your code goes, the only Qt-specific feature you've used is the signal-slot connection between your buttons and the main window. From your output - that you are getting "Confirming name" being output when clicking button 2 - this seems to be working correctly.

You problem is thus your code inside `MainWindow::confirmName()` itself.

```
1   qDebug() << "Confirming Name" << endl;
2   this->board->test();
3   Player ** tmp_player = this->board->getPlayer();
4   std::string tmp_string = tmp_player[0]->getName();
5   return tmp_string;
```

As seen by the output, line 1 is working so the problem lies further in the function.
You haven't supplied the code for the `Board` class or the `Player` class so it is impossible for any of us to say where the problem is exactly.

For your information:
You have a memory leak in your `setPlayer` function.

```
void MainWindow::setPlayer( int num ) {
    board= new Board( num );
    std::string name_string[2] = {"INPUT1","INPUT2"};
    board->addNames( name_string );
    qDebug() << QString::fromStdString( getName() ) << endl;
}
```

Every time you call this function, you are allocating a new `Board` object and the previous one gets lost. If you call the function four times, you will allocate four objects but only the last one is referenced by the `board` pointer. The rest are lost forever.

I suggest the following changes:

1. In your constructor add

   ```
   board = 0;
   ```
2. Change your `setPlayer` function to start with the following:

   ```
   if (board != 0) {
       delete board;
   }
   ```
3. Your `Board` class is returning a `Player **` from the `getPlayer()` function. Managing pointers is a challenge on its own. Managing pointers to pointers is even more difficult. I suggest using `QList<Player*>` instead. Qt has a number of very useful container classes, use them.

Comment: Note, in modern C++, `nullptr` should be used for a null pointer, instead of `0`.

Comment: Why? What's the difference?

Comment: One difference is overload resolution, a function might have overloads `void f(int)` and `void f(int*)`, so which one is `f(0)` going to call? Worst case, adding new overload will break old code, when it suddenly tries to call different function. And once need to use `nullptr` sometimes is established, it's better to be consistent and use it everywhere. Also, more subjective, it's clearer when you can right away see if something is pointer and not integer, which you can see with consistent use of `nullptr`, but not with `0`.